# how can I load word2vec model in payspark ml?

Tags: pyspark, word2vec

I try to load a trained word2vec model with following lines

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import Word2Vec

loadedWord2Vec = Word2Vec.load(W2V_MODEL_PATH)
```

but I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Word2VecModel.<init>(java.lang.String)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Word2VecModel instead of Word2Vec to load the model and problem solved.